# multiple ssl domain in single server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

I use digitalocean, to host 2 node.js app, one is staging and one is production. Both need ssl, I have the cert on my server. But I have problem running https for both.

```
//socket io config
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
let io = require('socket.io')(server)
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {

      let api_domain, https_port
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        api_domain = "api.example.co"
        https_port = 443
      } else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
        api_domain = "api-staging.example.co"
        https_port = 4431 //this is not working
      }

      const credentials = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(
          '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/privkey.pem',
          'utf8'
        ),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(
          '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/cert.pem',
          'utf8'
        ),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(
          '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/chain.pem',
          'utf8'
        )
      }

      const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)
//socket io config
  io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer)
  httpsServer.listen(https_port, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server started on: ' + port)
  })
    } else {
      //localhost
      server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('HTTP Server started on: ' + port)
      })
}
```

How should I configure the port correctly?

Comment: You want the server to run on port 443 if NODE_ENV is production and port 4431 if NODE_ENV is staging, right? Not both at the same time?

Comment: @josephting same time, it's 2 app on one droplet (server), but problem is if one is running, another will have error using the SSL port which by default is 443.

Comment: Then you only have to run multiple instances of the server. `NODE_ENV=production node index.js` in one window and `NODE_ENV=staging node index.js` in another. Both `https://api.example.co` and `https://api-staging.example.co:4431` should then be accessible at the same time.

Comment: @josephting i have multiple server running, https://api-staging.example.co:4431 is not accessible my server of https://api-staging.example.co start at port of 3001 while the production start at port of 3000.

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple Instances (Different Port)

In NodeJS, you cannot run multiple servers with a single node instance.

You will have to run multiple node instances with different `NODE_ENV` to have both servers run simultaneously.

Port 3000 and 3001 seems to be default port that was used by NodeJS. Make sure you have `NODE_ENV` specified properly.

```
//socket io config
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
let io = require('socket.io')(server)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {

  let api_domain, https_port
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    api_domain = "api.example.co"
    https_port = 443
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
    api_domain = "api-staging.example.co"
    https_port = 4431 //this is not working
  }

  const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(
      '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/privkey.pem',
      'utf8'
    ),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(
      '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/cert.pem',
      'utf8'
    ),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(
      '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + api_domain + '/chain.pem',
      'utf8'
    )
  }

  const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)
  //socket io config
  io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer)
  httpsServer.listen(https_port, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server started on: ' + https_port)
  })
} else {
  //localhost
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server started on: ' + port)
  })
}
```

Then, you want to launch 2 separate instance like so. *Assuming the file above is index.js*

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node index.js
HTTPS Server started on: 443

$ NODE_ENV=staging node index.js
HTTPS Server started on: 4431
```

You will then be able to access to the servers with the URLs below.

Do remember to have these domains resolve to the proper IPs.

**Production** - https://api.example.co

**Staging** - https://api-staging.example.co:4431

---

## Single Instance (Same Port)

If you want to differentiate the environment based on the hostname, you can use `request.headers.host` to determine where did the request came from and go from there.

However, you can only specify 1 certificate to be used per instance.

Below is one of the way you can achieve this.

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')

let app = function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
  if (req.headers.host === 'prod.dev.localhost') {
    res.write('Welcome to Production server.')
  } else if (req.headers.host === 'stg.dev.localhost') {
    res.write('Welcome to Staging server.')
  } else {
    res.write('Welcome!')
  }
  res.end()
}

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(path.dirname(__filename), 'cert', 'wildcard.dev.localhost.pem'),
    'utf8'
  ),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(path.dirname(__filename), 'cert', 'wildcard.dev.localhost.crt'),
    'utf8'
  )
}

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)
let io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer)

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS Server started on: ' + 443)
})
```

Comment: I'm running 2 instance. The problem is there's only one 443 port in a server.

Comment: @Melissa94 That's why you need to run staging on port 4431 instead.

Comment: @Melissa94 It is possible to run a single instance and serve multiple hostnames but you cannot load multiple certificates in a single instance. I've added more sample code in the answer. Using something like Nginx to handle that will be better if what you want to achieve is merely serving content over HTTPS.

Comment: @josepthing, production and staging is on 2 totally different domains, why you only have 1 cert? I use if else to use the correct cert, I did not spin up one node.js server but 2, and each server has one cert.

Comment: @Melissa94 That is exactly correct. Unfortunately, you cannot run 2 servers on the same port. That is why I suggested the **Multiple Instances** method at the top first. 2 options have been provided here for your reference. I'm using wildcard cert here which will work on all `*.dev.localhost` domain as an example.

Comment: I have multiple instances on one server (I mean cloud server not web server). I'm using pm2 to fire 2 instances using one set of code. I'm just curious where's is your another ssl cert? abc.com and stage.abc.com has different ssl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181647/discussion-between-josephting-and-melissa94).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not serving HTTPS use NodeJS.
Use nginx as a reverse proxy and provide https support is a better idea.

Just create two vhost in nginx with ssl certificate and `proxy_pass` to your nodejs app.

Comment: it's the same thing aren't it? in the end you have 2 port for one app, one is for normal http, one is for https.

Comment: @Melissa94 The result is the same …… in some way. As I think, handle HTTPS by NodeJS is quite inefficient. And next time maybe you change the domain or certificate, you need to redeploy the code.